# Gmail - any way to bypass autoresponder in a certain case?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email, automation

I am using Google Apps for Work.

I have a Google Apps account and mailbox (pmoore@example.com).

That mailbox has an alias assigned to it (inbox@example.com).

That mailbox has other aliases also assigned to it (patrick@example.com).

When I turn on Vacation Auto-Responder, it work as expected sending an automatic reply to any received messages (including those sent to the aliases).

What I want to achieve is for the Auto-Responder to NOT respond to any messages delivered to the (inbox@example.com) alias, but TO respond to all other messages delivered (including to the other aliases).

**Possible Solution:** I have considered a Filter, searching for to:pmoore@example.com,to:patrick@example.com, with the Send Canned Response option ticked in this case. This would work, but would be a bit of a pain to manage (updating Canned Response and re-activating Filter the Send Canned Response option every time I leave the office).

Has anyone encountered this problem and found any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I really like how the Gmail autoresponder works, so my approach would be to leave the autoresponder as is and work with the inbox@mydomain.com address differently. Google Apps has two alternatives.

- Delegated access. Create an account for inbox@mydomain.com and access it from your main account using [delegated access](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/170957?hl=en). Downside: This will require another Google Apps licence which is an added cost.
- Google Groups. Direct messages to general addresses, like inbox@, to Google Groups. There is no extra charge involved, multiple people can manage the messages in any particular [Google Group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en), and should you just want to have someone else manage the inbox@ messages in the future it's much easier to switch over access to the Group then it is to transfer an alias from one account to another.

Comment: +1 thank you, I was not familiar with Google Groups and this sounds like an interesting solution. I was trying to avoid creating another mailbox/user requiring an additional license.

Comment: That's great, I'm happy you found my answer useful. If you feel that this answers your question, please feel free to mark it as such.